# Command Prompt Alternative that can use Telnet

Tags: windows, command-line

I like console2 and Powercmd with all their extra features(tabs, font/color), but neither can use telnet, they seem to have their own commands. Is there a way to import the command list from command prompt into either of these?

I'm constantly telneting into devices. ConEmu seems to work with telnet but not directly with the command 'telnet x.x.x.x'. I have to first use 'telnet', then 'open x.x.x.x'.

Is there a nice cmd alternative that just takes all commands from cmd or one that has telnet?
Or is there a way to import commands from cmd with any of these?

Running Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, telnet is a standalone executable, not a command shell primitive.  But it isn't <s>shipped</s> installed by default with newer Windows systems.  You could [install the Microsoft version](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx) or use a third-party equivalent like [PuTTY/PuTTYtel](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or [dtelnet](http://dtelnet.sourceforge.net/).  Once you have a telnet program installed and in your path you're back to running it from the command prompt - whichever command shell you choose.

**Edit**

@Sunk818 comments that Telnet is, in fact, shipped.  I've corrected the phrasing above.  But given that the very article he quotes states that

> Telnet Client is not installed by default on Windows 7, Windows Server
>   2008 R2, Windows Vista, or Windows Server 2008.

it's easy to understand how one might make the blanket statement "it isn't shipped."  For kicks and giggles, I polled an example of four systems representing different OS, and it was a 2-and-2 split whether Telnet had been enabled or not.  Servers had been enabled, desktops hadn't.  Given that most people actually do their work from desktops, and given that this thread started with someone who didn't have it installed on their system, the distinction is kind of specious.

That said, I'm happy to learn that I can easily update Windows to include Telnet.  It's the only good port scanner Windows has.

[image: Windows 2003]
[image: Windows 7]
[image: Windows 2008 R2]
[image: Windows 8.1]

Comment: -1 according to this, Microsoft is shipping telnet http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx . Can you clarify what windows OS versions do not ship telnet and whether is workstation or server.

Comment: They include Telnet, it's just disabled by default these days. You have to add/enable it via Programs and Features.

Comment: I know that cmd can function with telnet. My problem is I have multiple windows up at once and it gets cumbersome. I want to have multiple tabs in one window and to costomize the font, and create hotkeys. Only an alternative program like console2 or powerCMD can do that, but they don't recognize the telnet command, only cmd does. I'm starting to think it has to do with me running 64bit windows, since powerCMD and console2 only run in 32bit, with the exception of comEmu...

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear.

> Is there a nice cmd alternative

Really? `cmd` is a shell that executes commands like `dir`, `cd`, `del` and so on. Are you really searching for cmd alternative?

> ConEmu seems to work with telnet but not directly with the command 'telnet x.x.x.x'

That is false. ConEmu works with **any** console application, which is telnet too of course.

> Or is there a way to import commands from cmd with any of these?

So what do you want exactly?

**Upd**

`telnet.exe` is not a "feature" of cmd.exe. It is standalone application located in system32. And of course, you do **not** need to run 64 bit shell to access it! Learn about Wow64 redirector in 64 bit windows )

That's how you may access them from any 32 bit shell

```
C:\windows\sysnative\telnet
```

To run it faster - use an alias or batch file.

Comment: ConEmu works with telnet, but you can't perform 'telnet x.x.x.x' in the shell, you have to first specify 'telnet', then once it pulls up telnet you have to use the command 'open x.x.x.x'. This isn't 'false', try it for yourself.

Every shell I've tried doesn't work with telnet, and the one that does(ConEmu) can only work the way I mentioned. I have telnet working in cmd, but no other shell can use it, they all say the command is unrecognized.

I just want multiple tabs, hotkeys, the ability to change my font, but without losing the ability to telnet.

Comment: Just words. Show exact examples of the problem. And why do you think that is ConEmu's problem but not a "shell" you are trying? what shell exactly?

Comment: Ok... download console2, or powerCMD, and open them, then try to telnet anywhere. Telnet is a feature and command of cmd. Telnet is also a feature on big routers. Telnet is used to access networking equipment remotely as if you were plugged directly up to it. What I'm saying is that when you open PowerCMD, or Console2, and use the telnet command, it is not recognized. But when you pull up cmd, it's recognized and works fine... The only thing I can find that is an issue is that most cmd substitutes are 32bit, and I'm running 64bit windows... Do you know of any 64bit shells?

Comment: You are absolutely wrong! Telnet *is not a cmd.exe feature* feature. Telnet.exe is standalone application located in system32, surprise!

Comment: ok? That still doesn't explain why a  3rd party shell can't use telnet, and you have suggested no alternatives that can use telnet in cli on a 64bit system...or the alterations to make so that a 32bit shell can use telnet on a 64bit os... which is what I've been asking for from the beginning...

Comment: Read my answer again, especially "Upd" section.

Comment: lol edited 5 hours ago, so I'll be reading the UDP section for the first time.That looks like like a winner though thanks, I'll check it out later today. +1.